# How to resolve flutter payment issue with setting theme.appcompat?

Tags: flutter, gradle, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

I am unable to set up the app theme properly in flutter. This is required by the flutter_stripe plugin.

I know the rest of my plugin works fine as it works on iOS.

This is the error I am getting on Android:

```
I/flutter (26094): ----------------FIREBASE CRASHLYTICS---------------- I/flutter (26094): PlatformException(flutter_stripe initialization failed, The plugin failed to initialize: I/flutter (26094): Your theme isn't set to use Theme.AppCompat or Theme.MaterialComponents. I/flutter (26094): Please make sure you follow all the steps detailed inside the README: https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe#android I/flutter (26094): If you continue to have trouble, follow this discussion to get some support https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/discussions/538, null, null) I/flutter (26094):  I/flutter (26094): #0      JSONMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:155:7) I/flutter (26094): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:177:18) I/flutter (26094): <asynchronous suspension> I/flutter (26094): #2      MethodChannelStripe.initialise (package:stripe_platform_interface/src/method_channel_stripe.dart:46:5) I/flutter (26094): <asynchronous suspension> I/flutter (26094): #3     Stripe._initialise (package:flutter_stripe/src/stripe.dart:424:5) I/flutter (26094): <asynchronous suspension> I/flutter (26094): #4     Stripe.initPaymentSheet (package:flutter_stripe/src/stripe.dart:317:5) I/flutter (26094): <asynchronous suspension> I/flutter (26094): #5    
_SellTicketsState.makePayment (package:eventiks/Screens/sell_tickets.dart:118:6) I/flutter (26094): <asynchronous suspension> I/flutter (26094):
----------------------------------------------------
```

I followed the steps [here](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe) for android.

My app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml looks like this:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is off -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.

         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

This shows in red by the way: Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar & Theme.MaterialComponents with the warning:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'Theme.MaterialComponents'

> Cannot resolve symbol 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'

I read online and found that I should add the following in gradle file:

> implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}


def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "uk.co.eelavan.eventiks"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My kotlin plugin version is:

> ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'

Which I did but I still get the error above. Need help, please!

Answer (score 3):

I'm using android 13 API level 33 and faced the same issue u can fix it buy updating the style.xml file in the following path:
"android>app>src>main>res>values-31>style.xml"
and apply the same provided settings by flutter-stripe documentation
hope it works for you

Answer (score 1):

style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is off -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.
         
         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
<!--    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">-->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.flutter.stripe.example

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
}
```

Comment: Yes, done these to

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you have to change style.xml in both folders

> values
> &
> values-night

I changed in both and it works now!

Answer (score 1):

If you're utilizing the flutter_native_splash package, you'll likely encounter two additional directories within your Android project structure, specifically located at android/app/src/main/res: values-v31 and values-night-v31.

copy the code from values/style.xml (as given in the stripe documentation)
and paste in values-v31/stlye.xml

do the same for values-night and values-night-v31

here is code for

android/app/src/main/res/values-night-v31/style.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is off -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.
         
         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

android/app/src/main/res/values-v31/style.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is off -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.
         
         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used to fix this.

values/styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is off -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!--
        Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
        Flutter draws its first frame
        -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">
            @drawable/launch_background
        </item>
    </style>
    <!--
    Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
    This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
    Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
    running.
    
    This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding.
    -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">
            ?android:colorBackground
        </item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

values-night/styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is on -->
    <!-- TODO document the necessary change -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!--
        Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
        Flutter draws its first frame
        -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">
            @drawable/launch_background
        </item>
    </style>
    <!--
    Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
    This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
    Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
    running.
    
    This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding.
    -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">
            ?android:colorBackground
        </item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Hope that helps!!!